# What sort of connection is used on this car remote antenna?

Tags: connector

I'm having issues with my car remote and looking at the antenna it looks like the wires were glued into the connection. I'd like to strip and replace this but I'm not sure what sort of connector to look for online/in stores to replace it.

This is almost identical to what I'm working with

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

When looking for the blue connector is this image what should I search for?

Comment: You'll need to give us, at least, a close-up of the connector viewed from the connection end to have any hope of identifying it. Use the unconnected end on the right.

Comment: @DrFriedParts Tried to find other images. Not at home at the moment but when I am I'll take some photos of my own. That's after I figure out how to turn off the alarm with a remote that's no longer working ...

Comment: Sounds like you bought your car at the same dealer I bought mine from!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a very common 2.54mm (0.1") rectangular connector.

The most popular by market volume is Molex's C-Grid series.

You will need to buy (or already have) three things to make these connectors:

#### 1. A housing

The housing is the connector's body. It is responsible for arranging the electrical contacts and protecting (or not) against inserting it upside-down (reversed insertion polarity).

This is a Molex 0050579204. It will fit your application, but it is not keyed (mechanically protected against incorrect insertion polarity) like your current connector (couldn't find an exact match).

[image]

You can buy them [here](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/0050579204/WM5364-ND/2731431) for about 1/2 USD each.

#### 2. A pin-crimp insert

These are the electrical contacts that attach your wire to the device. They sit inside the housing.

[image]

You buy some [here](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/0016020083/WM9139CT-ND/3676992) for a few cents each.

#### 3. A pin-crimp tool

A crimp tool crushes the electrical spines of the pin-crimp insert into the wire (a process called "crimping"). Most home electrical sets have a crimp tool. The difference with the C-grid (and most smaller-diameter electrical crimp systems) is that more precision is required. Hence, better more expensive tooling.

Comment: Using the housing you suggested I would just have to make sure I don't put it into the antenna in the incorrect direction. Other than that it should all be the same right?